# How to remove test:ws element from x:expect result in XSpec

Tags: xslt-2.0, xspec

Expected result throw by xspec:

```
<nl/>
<test:ws xmlns:test="http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/unit-test">
</test:ws>
```

Expected result i want  is our desired output element:

```
<nl/>
```

Comment: Have you written the template for `test:ws`?

Answer (score 0):

You Need to do 3 things in your XSLT:

1. Add namespace  `xmlns:test="http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/unit-test"`
2. Exclude namespace `exclude-result-prefixes="xs test"`
3. Write empty template for test:ws `<xsl:template match="test:ws"/>`

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <nl/>
    <test:ws xmlns:test="http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/unit-test"></test:ws>
</root>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:test="http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/unit-test"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs test" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="test:ws"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <nl/>

</root>
```

See below mentioned link for reference:

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rNa